# HListSum - Sum of HList's Nat's

Tags: scala

I wrote `HListSum`, whose type parameter is an input `HList`. Its `Out` type member represents the sum of that `HList`.

```
trait HListSum[L <: HList] {
  type Out <: Nat
}
object HListSum {

  type Aux[L <: HList, O <: Nat] = HListSum[L] { type Out = O }

  def apply[L <: HList](implicit ev: HListSum[L]): Aux[L, ev.Out] = ev

  implicit def hListSumInductive[H <: Nat, L <: HList, T <: Nat](
    implicit rest: HListSum.Aux[L, T],
             all: Sum[H, T]): HListSum.Aux[H :: L, all.Out] = new HListSum[H :: L] {
    type Out = all.Out
  }

  implicit val hlistSumHNil: HListSum.Aux[HNil, _0] = new HListSum[HNil] {
    type Out = _0
  }
}
```

Testing Examples:

```
import net.HListSum
import shapeless._
import nat._

scala> HListSum[_1 :: _2 :: HNil]
res0: net.HListSum[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0] :: shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]] :: shapeless.HNil]{type Out = shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]} = net.HListSum$$anon$4@5c609308

scala> val three: res0.Out = _3
three: res0.Out = Succ()

scala> HListSum[_1 :: _2 :: _5 :: HNil]
res1: net.HListSum[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0] :: shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]] :: shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]] :: shapeless.HNil]{type Out = shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]]]]]} = net.HListSum$$anon$4@79e8b4d0

scala> val eight: res1.Out = _8
eight: res1.Out = Succ()

scala> val error: res1.Out = _4
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : shapeless.nat._4
    (which expands to)  shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]
 required: res1.Out
    (which expands to)  shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]]]]]
       val error: res1.Out = _4
                             ^
```

I'm not sure if my approach is actually inductive since I'm referencing `all: Sum[H, T]`.

Please critique my `HListSum` for being idiomatic shapeless.